# Is there null in scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I tried the command that says hello who didn't registered the value at scoreboard "Checking_Saying". So I scripted command like this:

```
execute as @a[scores={Checking_Saying=NULL}] run say hello
```

But unfortunately, there was no such thing like "NULL". Is there any other way to check it?

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably thinking about Minecraft commands as a real programming language, but it isn't. It started from simple commands like teleportation, setting blocks, etc. and evolved into something that can be used for quite a lot, but it was never developed for that. If you think about it like a regular programming language, you'll encounter many cases like this, where something doesn't work quite as expected.

`null` doesn't even exist in all programming languages and in those where it exist, it can take many different forms, like `null`, `Null`, `NULL`, `undefined`, `nil`, `undef`, `Nothing`, etc. You can't expect it to work with the first spelling that comes to mind.

The closest you can get to `null` in Minecraft is a person that is not listed on a scoreboard. If it's an entity in the world (like a player, sheep or XP orb), you can target all that aren't in a scoreboard like this:

```
/execute as @e unless entity @s[scores={foo=..0}] unless entity @s[scores={foo=0..}] run <command>
```

You could also do it with one `unless`, but for that you would have to know the minimum and maximum value of a scoreboard and I also don't know that.

Comment: Also `unless score @s foo matches ..2147483647`

Comment: That's what I meant with knowing the numbers: `/execute as @e unless entity @s[scores={foo=-2147483648..2147483647}] run <command>`. I know `2147??????` by heart, but that's it. If you want to save 15 characters and a tiny bit of lag, you can also use that.